# Would these witnesses satisfy this big-O function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm trying to determine if $f(x) = \lceil x/2 \rceil$ is $O(x)$.

I know that this is true, and the textbook answer is:

$|\lceil x/2\rceil|\leq |(x/2)+1| \leq C|x|$ for all $x > 2$,

with witnesses $C = 1$, $k = 2$.

Would it also be correct if $C = 2$, $k = 0$? Or $C = 1,\ k = 1$? Just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
you need to show that
$|f(x)|
< cx
$
for some $c$
for all $x > x_0$
for some $x_0$.

Therefore
any
$c > \frac12$
will do for
large enough $x$.

I don't know why
the textbook talks about
"for all $x > 2$"
when all you need
is
"for all large enough $x$."

Comment: Ok cool. I take it my answers are fine then?

Comment: Generally, the smaller the initial value of $x$, the larger the constant $C$. This is because the small values can cause problems. The larger the initial $x_0$, the closer $C$ can be to the optimum value. In this case, you might like to show that, for any $C > \frac12$, there is an $x_0(C)$ such that $|f(x)| < Cx$ for $x > x_0(C)$.